# Cardinality in terms of $j$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm thinking of signing up to be a tutor and I'm reviewing material from a textbook to freshen up, but I've gotten stuck on this one. If we let $j \in \mathbb{N}$, how would we express the cardinalities in terms of $j$?

$\{h:\{1,2,\ldots,j\}\rightarrow \{1,2,\ldots,j\} |h$ is $1-1\}$

I don't know why, but I can't figure this one out.. I think it's the $1-1$ throwing me off but I've totally blanked at this point. Would the cardinality be $j!$

Comment: There are $j$ possible choices for $h(1)$. Then there are $j-1$ possible choices for $h(2)$. Then there are $j-2$ possible choices for... So the total number of _permutations_ is $j(j-1)(j-2)... = j!$

Comment: Also, because each $h$ is injective, or $1-1$, then since the domain and codomain have the same size, each h has to be surjective also, so they're all bijections.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Start with 1, what can 1 be mapped to (or how many elements can 1 be mapped to)? Now since h is 1-1, 2 cannot be mapped to the same element that 1 is mapped to. Can you continue this line of reasoning?